# How to get the primary key value of a row in a function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

I have a function in postgres that sends events on CRUD operations in my tables. However the problem is that it only works for tables that have an `id` column which is the primary key. How can I change this so that I can use whatever column is the primary key?

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
SET search_path = PUBLIC,
pg_catalog;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION psycopg2_pgevents_create_event() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $function$
  BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        PERFORM pg_notify('psycopg2_pgevents_channel',
        json_build_object(
            'event_id', uuid_generate_v4(),
            'event_type', TG_OP,
            'schema_name', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA,
            'table_name', TG_TABLE_NAME,
            'row_id', OLD.id            -------- this is not always "id"
        )::text
     );
         RETURN NULL;
    ELSE
        raise notice 'Value: %', NEW;
        PERFORM pg_notify('psycopg2_pgevents_channel',
            json_build_object(
                'event_id', uuid_generate_v4(),
                'event_type', TG_OP,
                'schema_name', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA,
                'table_name', TG_TABLE_NAME,
                'row_id', NEW.id,         -------- this is not always "id"
                'data', NEW
        )::text
    );
    RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
  END;
$function$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
SET search_path = "$user",
    PUBLIC;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a single primary key column, and you just want its value, you can extract it using:

```
to_jsonb(NEW)->>(
  SELECT attname
  FROM pg_attribute
  JOIN pg_index ON indexrelid = attrelid
  WHERE indrelid = TG_RELID
    AND indisprimary
)
```

If you've got multiple primary key columns, and/or you want to retrieve the PK in `{"key":"value"}` format, you could use:

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(attname, to_jsonb(NEW)->attname)
FROM pg_attribute
JOIN pg_index ON indexrelid = attrelid
WHERE indrelid = TG_RELID
  AND indisprimary
```